# Open activity after click in notification in alarmmanager and broadcast Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, notifications, alarmmanager

I set on my application the notification every 7 hours in this way:

```
  alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        // Setting the specific time for the alarm manager to trigger the intent, in this example, the alarm is set to go off at 23:30, update the time according to your need
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        val next=  calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 7

        calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, next)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,  0)

        // Starts the alarm manager
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.timeInMillis,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent
        )
```

with this class AlarmBroadcastReceiver :

```
class AlarmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            // Create the NotificationChannel
            val name = "Alarme"
            val descriptionText = "Detalhes do Alarme"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val mChannel = NotificationChannel("AlarmId", name, importance)
            mChannel.description = descriptionText
            val notificationManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
        }

        // Create the notification to be shown
        val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, "AlarmId")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_food)
                .setContentTitle("Synchronize Fitbit")
                .setContentText("Synchronize Fitbit data and log-in SugarFree for don't lose daily data")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        // Get the Notification manager service
        val am = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        // Generate an Id for each notification
        val id = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000

        // Show a notification
        am.notify(id.toInt(), mBuilder.build())
```

The notifications working well, I enter in the application, set the alarm and after 7 hours arrive the notification and so on. I wish that when arrive the notification i can click on it and open the app (maybe in my current home activity) so this alarm wish set automatically after 7 hours.
I saw that I must modify the pendingIntent with my home intent... but I have a

```
val intent = Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
```

that need to call the Alarm Receiver class.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to add `.setContentIntent` in your notification builder.

```
// Create the notification to be shown
        val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, "AlarmId")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_food)
                .setContentTitle("Synchronize Fitbit")
                .setContentText("Synchronize Fitbit data and log-in SugarFree for don't lose daily data")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context, // Context from onReceive method.
                    0,
                    Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java), // Activity you want to launch onClick.
                    0
                  )
                )
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .build()
```

You can find out more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation) the docs have more information about how to handle tasks such as only single Activity opens at a time.

Comment: I used your setContentIntet in my Builder! thank you help me more on this stuff!

Comment: @theantomc If my answer helps your need please accept it as an Answer to your question.
Yeah Sure, I can help you out in any of your problems if I can.
Thanks

Comment: @theantomc If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You need create and set  pending intent -

```
// Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
val resultIntent = Intent(this, YourMainActivity::class.java)
// Create the TaskStackBuilder
val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = TaskStackBuilder.create(this).run {
    // Add the intent, which inflates the back stack
    addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent)
    // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
    getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

and then set it -

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).apply {
    setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
    ...
}
with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
    notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
}
```

Hope this will work for you.